# all pushpins show up in the corner when binding to a map in a windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, bing-maps

When I bind an ObservableCollection to a map for pushpin data, all the pins show up in the upper left corner.  I have reproduced this in a simple app and don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Any help?

```xml
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="PushpinApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <my:Map Name="map1">
            <my:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}">
                <my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <my:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </my:MapItemsControl>
        </my:Map>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

```cs
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Thing> Stuff { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Stuff = new ObservableCollection<Thing>();
        Stuff.Add(new Thing() { Name = "one", Location = new GeoCoordinate(45.0, -110.0) });
        Stuff.Add(new Thing() { Name = "two", Location = new GeoCoordinate(40, -100) });

        DataContext = this;
    }
}

public class Thing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is the type of the 'Location' property `Location` and not `GeoCoordinate`?

Also, try putting the `MapItemsControl` in a `MapLayer`.

```
<map:Map CredentialsProvider="Your_Key">
    <map:MapLayer>
        <map:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}">
            <map:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <map:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </map:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </map:MapItemsControl>
    </map:MapLayer>
</map:Map>
```

Comment: The type needed to be GeoCoordinate.  (Thanks, not sure why I did that.)